# How to join computed fields from string operations in LINQ for Entity Framework Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, linq, join, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

If I want to join computed fields from string operations in a LINQ query, such as finding the substring before the first occurrence of a character, I get a translation error.

```
var items = from order in ordersList
                        let index = order.ItemName.IndexOf(',')
                        let end = index == -1 ? order.ItemName.Length : index
                        let orderHeader = order.ItemName.Substring(0, end)
                        join key in orderKeys on orderHeader equals key.orderHeader
                        select order;
```

, where orderKeys is a list of orderHeaders. How would I write this query, or is another option possibly to create a get `OrderHeader` property in the model itself?

Comment: Is `ordersList` InMemory? It seems EF is unable to translate this query into SQL. Try loading the `ordersList` collection in memory and then run this query. You can use the `ToList()` method to do so.

Comment: Sometimes exception messages are actually useful. What did it tell you?

Comment: @PrashantTiwari ordersList is IQueryable and not in memory. However, it is rather large so it would be preferable not to load it into memory.

Comment: @GertArnold It says "The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList() or ToListAsync()".

Comment: Your current query is loading the entire set nevertheless. You might want to filter out some data using `Where`, `Skip` or `Take` if that's possible. The reason you're getting this issue that EF does not know how to translate the `?`, `SubString` operations into  SQL. Alternative approach would be to use an ORM tool such as Dapper. EF is a double edged sword my friend.

Comment: The exception message says a lot more. Don't just ignore it. Look at it closely. It probably answers your question.

Comment: some data example would be helpful